# Want user to input number for for loop to run Javascript

Tags: javascript

Trying to have a user input a number and if they type in a string I would like to prompt them to enter a number. Seems like I got that part right but how can I get the second prompt to keep popping up until the user enters a an actual number. As of now, once the user enters a string again nothing runs after that. Would appreciate any kind of suggestions.

Here is the code:

```
function enterNumber(n) {

    n = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number: "));

    if (isNaN(n)) {
        n = parseInt(prompt("You did not enter a number. Please enter a number: "));

            for(var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

            if (i % 15 === 0) {
                document.write("Fizz Buzz" + "<br>");
                continue;
            }
            else if (i % 3 === 0){
                document.write("Fizz" + "<br>");
                continue;
            } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
                document.write("Buzz" + "<br>");
                continue;
            }
            document.write(i + "<br>");
        }
    }

};
enterNumber();
```

Comment: Give them a input field, and only run the function which has the loop if the input is a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `while` loop until the entered is number.

```js
function enterNumber(n) {
  while (isNaN(parseInt(n))) {
    n = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number: "));
  }

  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

    if (i % 15 === 0) {
      document.write("Fizz Buzz" + "<br>");
      continue;
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
      document.write("Fizz" + "<br>");
      continue;
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
      document.write("Buzz" + "<br>");
      continue;
    }
    document.write(i + "<br>");
  }

};

enterNumber();
```

You can also shorten you code using nested Ternary operators as follow.

```js
function enterNumber(n) {
  while (isNaN(parseInt(n))) {
    n = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number: "));
  }

  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    var title = i % 15 === 0 ? 'Fizz Buzz' : i % 3 === 0 ? 'Fizz' : i % 5 === 0 ? 'Buzz' : i;
    document.write(title + "<br>");
  }
};

enterNumber();
```

Comment: Oh thats even better I am gonna read up on that...looks like it will make life a lot easier

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```js
function enterNumber(n) {


  while (isNaN(n))
    n = parseInt(prompt("You did not enter a number. Please enter a number: "));


  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

    if (i % 15 === 0) {
      document.write("Fizz Buzz" + "<br>");
      continue;
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
      document.write("Fizz" + "<br>");
      continue;
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
      document.write("Buzz" + "<br>");
      continue;
    }
    document.write(i + "<br>");
  }


};
enterNumber();
```